# Añadir imagen en XML

Tags: xml, imagen, xsl

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando crear un **XSL** donde, en una tabla, mostrar el contenido de unos artículos de un **XML**, y estos artículos llevan una imagen.

Llevo ya un rato intentando añadir una imagen al XML para luego llamarlo en el XSL.

Estoy probando esto en el **XML**:

```
<articulo categoria="Informatica">

<nombre>Ordenador Gaiming</nombre>
<descripcion>Ordenador preparado para jugar</descripcion>
<precio>1500</precio>
<imagen enlace="imagenes/logo.jpg"></imagen>

</articulo>
```

Y así lo llamo en el **XSL**:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="imagen/@enlace"/>
</td>
```

Pero la verdad, es que solo me muestra el "texto". **¿Como se añade una imagen en el XML?**

Comment: Prueba llamando al elemento y su atributo desde la raíz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale ya lo conseguí. Dejo el como lo he resuelto...

En la parte del **XML** basta con dejar la ruta dentro de la etiqueta de esta forma:

```
<articulo categoria="Informatica" descuento="10">

<nombre>Monitor</nombre>
<descripcion>Full HD</descripcion>
<precio>340</precio>
<imagen>imagenes/monitor.jpg</imagen>

</articulo>
```

Después, en el **XSL** debemos de llamarlo así:

```
    <td>
        <img>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
             <xsl:value-of select="imagen"/>
          </xsl:attribute>       
        </img>
    </td>
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda a próximos usuarios :)